# I want to run a PHP daemon on a shared hosting?

Tags: php, daemon

How? Is it possible? If not what are my alternatives?

May be python daemon?

Edit: My aim is to play with custom protocols in the internet (online).

Comment: Can you flesh your question out a bit more. What sort of shared hosting? Which provider? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: PHP is not suited for running in daemon mode.

Comment: @MarcB care to share why it isn't?

Comment: This sounds like it would be a great question for your hosting provider.  Specifically the parts about what background tasks you can run and what your alternatives are.

Comment: The shared hosting provider is tophost.bg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two aspects to be considered here:

1. does your shared hosting provider allow you to run daemons?  Most probably not, in that case a cron task might be an alternative solution.
2. How to technically create a daemon?  There's a [PEAR package](http://pear.php.net/package/System_Daemon) that, at least for Linux, does whatever's needed to convert your script to a daemon.

Now, some webhosters don't even offer cronjobs, in that case using an external service like [setcronjob](https://www.setcronjob.com/) that's configured to regularly call a php script on your website can be used as a last alternative to switching hosters.

Comment: cron tasks probably won't help because then PHP-daemon won't be able to listen all the time I guess?

Comment: @george true, cron scripts can't permanently listen, they're not a universal substitute for a daemon but I still wanted to mention them as an alternative for certain use cases given the issues you might encounter to run a daemon on a shared hosting package.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all shared hosting sites will kill any process that runs longer than a certain amount of time, typically 30 seconds.

Your best bet is probably a cron task, as this will run your script once every time specified.

That said, if you're doing something that seriously needs a PHP daemon, you should probably be on shared hosting and exhausted all other options in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If you can run background tasks or Cron jobs, you can probably run a daemon. They may have limits on how long processes can run but in most cases if they cared about that, they wouldn't give you access in the first place.

I suggest using https://github.com/shaneharter/PHP-Daemon instead of System_Daemon. It's a better abstraction, and provides a real way to build multi-process apps in PHP without having to stitch it all together yourself.